# typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, leap-year

I am trying to determine if these years are leap years.
1900, 1999, 2000, 2001,2002,2003,2004

```
def leapyr(n):
    if (n%4==0) and (n%100!=0):
        if (n%400==0):
            print (n, " is a leap year.")
    elif (year%4!=0):
        print (n, " is not a leap year.")

numbers = [(1900),(1999),(2000),(2002),(2003),(2004),]

results=[]

for x in numbers:
    print(leapyr(numbers))
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gx2410ls/hw 12.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(leapyr(numbers))
  File "C:/Users/gx2410ls/hw 12.py", line 2, in leapyr
    if (n%4==0) and (n%100!=0):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: As per the traceback, `n` is a list. You can't mod lists. You should look through your code and work out why `n` is a list.

Comment: `print(leapyr(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the wrong value. Use

```
print(leapyr(x))
```